# How to use APEX_COLLECTION package inside custom pl/sql package?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on an PL/SQL package that should perform some work on apex_collection. Nothing special I just want to centralize my PL/SQL code that create/update/delete collections. And make it easely reusable by my colleagues. Basically what I am trying to do is to crete a pl/sql package that mapps collection fields' names to table column's name, so there will be smaller posibility to visualize the wrong column in the report ore commit some other mistake due to not readability of apex_collection fields' names.

I am using collection to handle data rollback in case the user session get expaired or user leave the page unexpectedly (pc shuts down unexpectadly etc.).

So **my main problem** is that I can't access APEX_COLLECTION from my editor (DataGrip maybe it may provide some aditional info). I am getting undefined `Unable to resolve symbol 'APEX_COLLECTION'` .
Most of apex releted schemas seem to be empty (APEX_PUBLIX_USER) or don't have APEX_COLLECTION definition.
Did somebody have similar issue with OraclXE/Apex?

Versions
apex 5.1
Oracle 11

Comment: If the database schema is added to the workspace, then APEX_COLLECTION should be available. I'm not sure if that would be different for XE - maybe others know.

Comment: Ok, I will try to add them all to see what will heppe.

Comment: It helped thanks. The actual definition of appex collection was in Public schema.